# How to automatically install python packages when using CPanel with Continuous Deployment?

Tags: deployment, pip, github-actions, cpanel, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to make a Continuous Deployment workflow using GitHub Actions to deploy on shared Hosting (CPanel).

I have setup a workflow for serving the frontend static pages through the use of the library FTP-Deploy-Action. https://github.com/SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action

Now I wish to use it deploy my python backend too. I have created a python app and setup the libraries but I wish to be able to pip install any new packages I add later on.

I know there is a .cpanel.yml file that is suppose to automate Deployment but all the examples I have found consists of just copying files from one directory to another.

This is my current github actions `main.yml` file which is making it possible to CD my frontend files.

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - staging

name:  Deploy website on push (staging)
jobs:
  web-deploy:
    name:  Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name:  Get latest code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name:  Build Project
      run: |
        npm install
        npm run build
    
    - name:  Sync files (Frontend)
      uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.3.0
      with:
        server: ${{ secrets.ftp_username }}
        username: ${{ secrets.ftp_username }}
        password: ${{ secrets.ftp_password }}
        server-dir: /public_http/
        exclude: |
          **/.git*
          **/.git*/**
          **/node_modules/**
          **/env/**
          **/mywebsite/**
          README.md
          requirements.txt
```

I have tried to make this into

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - staging

name:  Deploy website on push (staging)
jobs:
  web-deploy:
    name:  Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name:  Get latest code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    - name:  Sync files (Frontend)
      uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.3.0
      with:
        server: ${{ secrets.ftp_server }}
        username: ${{ secrets.ftp_username }}
        password: ${{ secrets.ftp_password }}
        server-dir: /public_html/
        exclude: |
          **/.git*
          **/.git*/**
          **/node_modules/**
          **/env/**
          **/mywebsitebackend/**
          README.md
          requirements.txt

    - name:  Sync files (Backend)
      uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.3.0
      with:
        server: ${{ secrets.ftp_server }}
        username: ${{ secrets.ftp_username }}
        password: ${{ secrets.ftp_password }}
        server-dir: /mywebsitebackend/
        exclude: |
          **/.git*
          **/.git*/**
          **/node_modules/**
          **/env/**
          README.md
          index.html
```

This can theoretically copy the files into the proper directories but I wish to be able to run `python pip install -r requirements.txt` on my remote server automatically.

Is there anyway to run pip install automatically on CPanel?

PS.I read about the Pull and Push workflow but couldn't find a desireable outcome. I wish to push to my github repo and have it all be done automatically.